# Caching DTO classes in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

We are using MongoDb as caching service for caching our TDO classes which are widely used in our Visual Studio solution.
MongoDB requires the _id field on stored objects so every DTO class must have the _id property.
This requirement exposes concrete implementation on the DTOs.
How can we overcome it?

Comment: Create a business object from your DTO. The rest of the application should use the business object. Only the data layer should use the DTO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on the answer provided by @Rahul, the MongoDB C# driver provides the annotation `[BsonElement("<name>")]` to help [serialize documents with the CSharp driver](https://mongodb-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver.html).

```
public class Entity
{
    [BsonElement("_id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class DTO : Entity 
{
    [BsonElement("bd")]
    public DateTime BusinessDate { get; set; }

    // etc
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution here so far.
But still we'll need to keep refernce to MongoDB assembley with the DTO library assembley which is in OO terms is a implementation leak.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's true that `MongoDB` requires event entity (document) must have a `_id` field. Since in your case every entity (DTO) must have the Id field, you can create a base entity and have all your DTO (concrete entities) derive from it like

```
public class BaseDTO
{
  public string _id {get; set;}
}

public class DTO1 : BaseDTO 
{
  // your specific implementation
}
```

You can as well consider creating your collection same as POCO structure.

Comment: You can annotate the property with `[BsonElement("_id")]` to allow more friendly naming as `public string Id {get;set;}`